# ERROR: license_key is empty in the config. Not starting New Relic Agent

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, newrelic, buildpack, apm

I am facing the below error log on Spring Boot application startup. But the application is properly up and running.

**2023-09-07T13:06:34,626+0000 [1 1] com.newrelic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEK09.png)**

## build.gradle.kts

```
tasks.named<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    buildpacks(listOf("urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java", "docker.io/paketobuildpacks/new-relic"))
    bindings(listOf("/home/XX/Desktop/new_relic/odata-api/bindings/new-relic:/platform/bindings/new-relic"))
}
```

## directory structure :

It consists of LK as well

I am using below docker command to up the application

```
docker run -p 9090:9090  --volume /home/XX/Desktop/new_relic/odata-api/bindings/new-relic:/platform/bindings/new-relic -e JAVA_OPTS="-DDATABASE_URL=XX -DDATABASE_NAME=XX -DDATABASE_USER=XX -DDATABASE_PORT=1433 -DDATABASE_PASSWORD=XX -DDATABASE_SCHEMA=XX" XXX:32.0.0
```

Tec Stack is :

Spring Boot, Kotlin (build.gradle.kts), Docker, and host in Azure.

I am expecting to integrate Relic agent with my module, by fixing above mentioned issue

Comment: did you try to pass your NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY as an environment variable when you run your container?
For example, your run command would be:
`docker run -p 9090:9090  -e NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=XXX -e JAVA_OPTS="-DDATABASE_URL=XX -DDATABASE_NAME=XX -DDATABASE_USER=XX -DDATABASE_PORT=1433 -DDATABASE_PASSWORD=XX -DDATABASE_SCHEMA=XX" XXX:32.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

As described in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064289/error-license-key-is-empty-in-the-config-not-starting-new-relic-agent#comment135881782_77064289), you need to tweak your run configuration to pass your license key (you built correctly).

You have 2 ways of doing this:

- using plain old container environment variables (in this case `-e NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=XXX`)

```
docker run -p 9090:9090  -e NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=XXX -e JAVA_OPTS="-DDATABASE_URL=XX -DDATABASE_NAME=XX -DDATABASE_USER=XX -DDATABASE_PORT=1433 -DDATABASE_PASSWORD=XX -DDATABASE_SCHEMA=XX" XXX:32.0.0
```

- using the Paketo bindings way with such a binding (beware to not add the `NEW_RELIC_` prefix when inside the binding folder):

```
tree bindings-runtime/
bindings-runtime/
└── newrelic
    ├── LICENSE_KEY
    └── type
```

(by the way you could have re used the initial binding; no need to have 2 different ones)

and run with:

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 --env SERVICE_BINDING_ROOT=/platform/bindings  --volume $PWD/bindings-runtime/newrelic:/platform/bindings/newrelic -e JAVA_OPTS="-DDATABASE_URL=XX -DDATABASE_NAME=XX -DDATABASE_USER=XX -DDATABASE_PORT=1433 -DDATABASE_PASSWORD=XX -DDATABASE_SCHEMA=XX" XXX:32.0.0
```